# Copy data from one spreadsheet file to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that I use to track my open crypto trades. The information consists of 4 columns. ("Coin", "Date", "Time" and "Price"). This information is not available to the public. When trades are closed I complete the next 3 columns ("Date", "Time" and "Price") and copy all 7 columns across to a different spreadsheet that is available to the public. There are other columns in this public spreadsheet that contain formulae that calculate trade profit and loss, weekly summary and monthly summary.

I have written the following code in Google Apps Script and attached it to a button on one of the spreadsheets to automate this task. I need all users to be able to run the code by clicking the button. Currently there are 4 users. My code does all of this automatically except, because I open a new spreadsheet part way through the script, none of the values collected before that point are available to be inserted into the target spreadsheet.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function updatePublicSheet(){
  var coinBought;
  var dateBought;
  var timeBought;
  var priceBought;
  var dateSold;
  var timeSold;
  var priceSold;
  var lrIndex;
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBGpD0nUqCGtQqq78svw4fxA4ZgwBqV2yzIbgY1tY2o/edit#gid=1107419239"); 
  var sSheet = sss.getSheetByName('SS Open Trades');
  var sRng = sSheet.getRange("F3:H").getValues();

  // Find last entry in columns F, G or H in the Open Trades sheet
  for (var i = sRng.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    var lrIndex = i;
      if (!sRng[i].every(function(c){return c == "";})){
        break;
      }
    }
    //  Logger.log("Last row is %s", lrIndex + 3);

    // Check that the closed information has been added to all columns
    // index 6 = 6th column = F = dateSold
    // index 7 = 7th column = G = timeSold
    // index 8 = 8th column = H = priceSold

    if ((sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),6).getValue().length) == 0 ||
      (sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),7).getValue().length) == 0 ||
      (sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),8).getValue().length) == 0){
      //Logger.log("Trade close information is not complete");
        return;
        }
  
  // If there is a complete closed entry, copy the values to the variables
  if (lrIndex > 0)
    {
      coinBought = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),2).getValue();
      dateBought = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),3).getValue();
      timeBought = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),4).getValue();
      priceBought = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),5).getValue();
      dateSold = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),6).getValue();
      timeSold = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),7).getValue();
      priceSold = sSheet.getRange((lrIndex + 3),8).getValue();
      //Logger.log(coinBought);
    }

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1umkTCr95FZUrZzv0e_ZDD9QZYiiYuH1fJohPYQzNE9Q/edit#gid=1644116137"); 
  var tSheet = tss.getSheetByName('Trade Tracker');
  var tRng = tSheet.getRange("A3:H").getValues();

  // Create a new row at Row 4 on the Trades Tracker Sheet
  tSheet.insertRows(5, 1);//shift all rows down by one from row 5

  // Copy values from row 4 to row 5, including the formulae
  var tRange = tSheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 26);
  tRange.copyTo(tSheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, 26), {contentsOnly:false});

  // Populate row 4, first 7 table columns, from the variables
  //Logger.log(coinBought);
  tSheet.getRange(4,2).setValue(coinBought);
  tSheet.getRange(4,3).setValue(dateBought);
  tSheet.getRange(4,4).setValue(timeBought);
  tSheet.getRange(4,5).setValue(priceBought);
  tSheet.getRange(4,6).setValue(dateSold);
  tSheet.getRange(4,7).setValue(timeSold);
  tSheet.getRange(4,8).setValue(priceSold);

  // Sort the sheet by date/time closed
    // Find last entry in Trade Tracker sheet
  for (var i = tRng.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    var lrIndex = i;
      if (!tRng[i].every(function(c){return c == "";})){
        break;
      }
    }
    Logger.log("Last row is %s", lrIndex + 4);

  var tRange = tSheet.getRange(4, 2, lrIndex + 4, 11)
  tRange.sort([{column: 6, ascending: false}, {column: 7, ascending: false}]);

  // On the source sheet, delete the row just copied and add another blank row

  // Success message

}
```

Comment: I'd have to see an image of sSheet.  Also everything below and including this line `var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1umkTCr95FZUrZzv0e_ZDD9QZYiiYuH1fJohPYQzNE9Q/edit#gid=1644116137"); ` is not contained within a function declaration .  So none of the variables defined within the function are defined for those lines.  Try including everything in the function.

Comment: I just extended the function declaration to include all of the code and it is now working. Thanks so much. It was driving me mad.

Comment: The "Sort" part was not working.  No sort is carried out at all. However, I have prelaced it with this code, but is not working either. Can anyone spot what is wrong?
```
// Sort the sheet by date/time closed
    // Find last entry in Trade Tracker sheet
  for (var i = tRng.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    var lrIndex = i;
      if (!tRng[i].every(function(c){return c == "";})){
        break;
      }
    }
    Logger.log("Last row is %s", lrIndex + 4);

  var tRange = tSheet.getRange(4, 2, lrIndex + 4, 11)
  tRange.sort([{column: 6, descending: true}, {column: 7, descending: true}]);
```

Comment: Please post the code properly in your question.  It makes it easier for all of us.

Comment: What are column 6  and column 7? And you have not updated all of you changes in the code in your question.  If you have date in one column and time in another that's probably why it's not sorting.  Use a proper datetime object instead.  Otherwise it just performs a string sort.   You can also do the sort with a datetime object and use a compare function for the sort by converting all date strings to a date object and comparing with valueOf().

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect my current script. In the target sheet, column 6 is dateSold and column 7 if timeSold, the two parameters on which I wish to sort the sheet, newest entries at the top.

Comment: Are column 6 and  7 date objects or strings.  If they are strings I need to see some examples.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

The script should run under an account that has access to the source spreadsheet. Therefore, executing this via button will not work, since the function will always execute under the user who clicked the button, and that, as I understood, might not have access to the non-public spreadsheet.

#### Solution:

Therefore, you should execute it a different way. I'd suggest the following:

- **With an account that has access to the source spreadsheet**, install an `onEdit` trigger, either manually, by following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit()), by copying this function to your editor and executing it once:

```
function installOnEdit() {
  var sss SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("TARGET_SPREADSHEET_URL");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("updatePublicSheet")
    .forSpreadsheet(sss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

- Add a checkbox to a cell in the target spreadsheet.
- Modify your function so that it only updates a spreadsheet if the checkbox cell is edited. You can use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) for this:

```
function updatePublicSheet(){
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "CHECKBOX_SHEET"; // Name of the sheet where the checkbox is found, change accordingly
  var checkboxNotation = "A1"; // Notation of the checkbox cell, change accordingly
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetName && range.getA1Notation() === checkboxNotation) {
    // YOUR OLD CODE
    range.uncheck();
  }
}
```

Once you do that, every time the checkbox is clicked by anyone, the taget spreadsheet is updated.

#### Note:

- Using `getValue` and `setValue` to get or set values to multiple cells is not recommended. You can use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to grab and modify many cell values at once, minimizing the amount of calls to the Sheets service you make. See [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Comment: I have updated the code for the sort that I needed. It is all working fine now.

Thanks for all the work lamblichus. That will be useful for something I will need in the future. The four users that have the ability to make entries into the source spreadsheet also have access to click the button to copy the data across to the publicly available sheet. So it is less complicated than you imagined.

Comment: @1ClickTrading Hi, if the solution you came up with is not the same as the proposed answer, would you consider posting an answer yourself, explaining what you did?